# How to change background image on android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have several images, and I want the app user to be able to change the background image of the current activity he is in. How can I be able to do this?

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: @pgiitu I have created my activity that contains the text view of a quote and it has a button in the bottom part of the screen that sends me to another activity where I have the quote and a button that it supposed to change my background image.. But I don't know how to make the user view the background options so he can choose the new background

Comment: What is the source of the images? I mean, from where does the user choose an image to set as the background?

Comment: @GirishRaman I want the images to be stored inside the app, they are like 4 or 5 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a typed array in arrays.xml file within your res folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@drawable/car_01</item>
        <item>@drawable/balloon_random_02</item>
        <item>@drawable/dog_03</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Then in your activity,if you want to change background.Write below code for Button onClick() access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
//get resourceid by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)
// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

Comment: great! I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for! thank you so much!

Comment: one more question! where do I declare the i? or what does is stand for in this case? is it the position of the images inside the array?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewbie Yes it is the position of the images inside the array.i am sure it is working fine,please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is by using handlers. You can call the postDelayed() and set the background periodically. Make sure the runnable thread which sets the background checks if the activity is currently in foreground.

Comment: the questions says how to change it..not set it

Answer (score 0):

In xml file
In layout tag:

```
android:background="@drawable/yourImage"
```

yourImage must be storage in `drawable` folder